# When second time use function, List is empty

Tags: c#, list

My function working only after compile. When it go second time it doesn't work.

I have function which add new items to my list.

```
    public void addToDetailList()
    {
        tablist.Add(new OneStudentEvent()
        {
            Indeks = oneEvent.Indeks,
            Parts = oneEvent.Parts,
            Present = oneEvent.Present,
            PresentcString = oneEvent.PresentString
        });
    Console.Write("\nCount: " + tablist.Count);
    }
```

And in other function i have return to this tablist.

```
    public List<OneStudentEvent> getDetailEventInfo()
    {
        Console.Write("\ndb. Count on return: " + tablist.Count);
        return tablist;
    }
```

When I compile and run program for first time everything is ok.
But in second time, tablist.Count=0.

Before input to addToDetailList() clear my list:

```
        if(tablist.Count>0)
        {
            for (int i = tablist.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                tablist.RemoveAt(i);
                    Console.Write("\nUSUWAM WIERSZE Z LISTY element: " +i);
            }
        }
```

Output:

Count: 5
Count on return: 5

Count: 5
Count on return: 0

Comment: Where is tablist defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getDetailEventInfo` is returning a pointer to `tablist`. That is, it is *not* generating a new list.

Running `var myList = getDetailEventInfo()` and then removing items from the `tablist` means you are removing items from the `myList` list *as well*. The are one and the same.

If you change your method to be instead:

```
return tablist.ToList();
```

Then you will be returning a brand new list (which is a copy of the source), and your code will work as expected.

Comment: my steps:

1:removing - if (Count>0)

2.addToDetailList()

3 getDetailEventInfo()


So i should resign with removing?
Or i should read something about "this."

Comment: @zdunek25 You don't have to remove anything.. simply add `.ToList()` at the end of `getDetailEventInfo` :)